# how to specialize the groups of data in SQL report?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, reporting

I've written a sql query where I selected data by grouping them on users and actions (added/changed).

Everything works great, however, when I run report it shows data a bit inconvenient to read.

The long of "Aded" field based on the amount of outputted rows

is it possible to specialize the long to fit of the field name ?

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: It may be just my, but I'm having some language issues, as I don't quite understand your question. Could you edit to clarify?

Comment: "Aded" should be added. Are you trying to adjust the height or the width? Width can't be changed dynamically. By default, the height will grow to fit whatever data is populated.

Comment: yeah, sorry, there is a spelling mistake) I'm talking about the height

Comment: @Leo are your rows that high in design view or just when you preview it?

Comment: @StevenWhite In the preview view, man